# Java-конфигурация log4j

Tags: java, логирование, log4j

Мне нужно что бы при достижении определенного размера, файл лога создавался новый и их могло быть к примеру 5 штук всего. И после того как будет достигнуто максимальное количество что бы процесс начался заново.

У меня есть конфигурация:

```
    // creates pattern layout
    PatternLayout layout = new PatternLayout();

    String conversionPattern = "%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n";
    layout.setConversionPattern(conversionPattern);

    // creates console appender
    ConsoleAppender consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender();
    consoleAppender.setLayout(layout);
    consoleAppender.activateOptions();

    // creates file appender
    FileAppender fileAppender = new FileAppender();
    fileAppender.setFile("../main.log");
    fileAppender.setBufferSize(fileAppender.getBufferSize()*2);
    fileAppender.setLayout(layout);
    fileAppender.activateOptions();


    // configures the root logger
    Logger rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger();
    rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ALL);
    rootLogger.addAppender(consoleAppender);
    rootLogger.addAppender(fileAppender);
```

в одной из статей на `habrahabr` я нашел такую конфигурацию

```
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern = application_log.txt
java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 1000000
java.util.logging.FileHandler.count = 5
java.util.logging.FileHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

**Вопрос**: как повторить такую же конфигурацию но в коде? и как вообще лучше организовать работу с файлами логера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен [RollingFileAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html). "Этот аппендер позволяет ротировать файл по достижении определенного размера. "Ротировать" означает, что текущему файлу приписывается расширение ".0" и открывается следующий. По достижении им максимального размера – первому вместо расширения ".0" выставляется ".1", текущему – ".0", открывается следующий. И так далее. Максимальный размер файла и максимальный индекс, устанавливаемый сохраняемым предыдущим файлам, задаются свойствами maximumFileSize и maxBackupIndex соответственно. Если индекс должен быть превышен – файл не переименовывается, а удаляется. Таким образом мы всегда имеем не больше определенного количества файлов, каждый из которых не больше определенного объема. Гораздо более предсказуемая ситуация, чем с обычным FileAppender-ом. Собственно, этот тип аппендеров, наверное, самый используемый".
(с) *www.skipy.ru - Ведение лога приложения*

```
# Уровень логирования
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file

# Апендер для работы с файлами
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
# Путь где будет создаваться лог файл
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\TMP\\log_file.log
# Указываем максимальный размер файла с логами
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
# Указываем максимальное количество файлов
log4j.appender.file.maxBackupIndex=5
```

Comment: А как понять эту строку "Если индекс должен быть превышен – файл не переименовывается, а удаляется." ?? Если я к примеру хоче что бы у меня был один файл и при достижении ним максимального размера он заново или удалялся и создавался заново - какое значение нужно установить maxBackupIndex ?

Comment: Наверное 1... попробуйте.